# How to programmatically find the default installation directory for the given OS and user, thru Java?

Tags: java

I need to find the directory that will be used by default by the given OS and user combination for installing a new application. For example, on Windows, for any user, that directory could be `C:\Program Files`; for Linux + root, it could be `/usr/local`; for Linux + non-root user, it could be `/home/username` etc.

Comment: I think that there is an environment variable for that.

Comment: I am looking for an OS-agnostic way to obtain that path.

Comment: Are you looking for the path where the application is installed, or the path where the application data is stored?

Comment: @EmmanuelBourg, where application is installed.

Comment: Would one of the open source installers written in Java like izpack have the code you need?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, it's a large project. All I could find was [this method](https://github.com/jponge/izpack/blob/master/izpack-panel/src/main/java/com/izforge/izpack/panels/path/PathInputPanel.java#L336). I'd appreciate if you could point me to the source file where this `PathInputPanel#defaultInstallDir` field is set.

Comment: I do not know - I am not familiar with the izpack source.  Try setting up your IDE to work with the izpack source, and use the navigation tools familiar to you to locate all usages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its too late to reply this thread or not.But even I was in need for something similar using Java.

Finally I found that for fetching System environment variables, java provides two methods

```
1>System.getenv(name)
```

here name is the key for which one needs the value.It returns "String"
The other one is

```
2> System.getenv();
```

This returns all the system environment variables.It returns "Map".

I would insist you use the second method initially and know all the key-value pairs for the OS you are using.Then the moment you get the proper key name for the property you need to fetch ,you can go ahead for the first method.

Also do check the Java documentation in case you need more clarity.
[javadoc link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)